# Android eclipse run program causes Installation error: 0

Tags: android, eclipse

I have an Android application. In the latest version I've moved some code from it into separate Android Library projects (two). One library depends on another and project depends on both libraries. So, as I understand, one library includes into final application "twice" (or something similar to twice).

On the first launch of application I receive following in Console (I am using Eclipse):

`Installation error: 0
Please check logcat output for more details.
Launch canceled!`

Can anybody help? 
Thanks!

**EDIT**

On the second launch program starts normally.

**EDIT**

I tried to reproduce error on the emulator and other device, it didn't reproduce! Can a problem be on my device? May be on file not deleted or something else?

Comment: and... what´s the logcat output telling?

Comment: Nothing, application filter is empty. Unfiltered messages also don't have any relational info.

Comment: Usual suspects? Repeated package name from app to lib?

Comment: Is the support lib placed in a separate project?

Comment: Minor-major sdk version disagree?

Comment: Package names are different, support lib is used only in main project, minor version 9 for all libs except one - 7 for it. Major version is 21 for all.

Comment: I tried to reproduce error on the emulator and other device, it didn't reproduce! Can a problem be on my device? May be on file not deleted or something else?

Comment: try uninstalling and make a clean installation. And check the device API level, sounds like the instalation is checking something and not telling you about it. If u´ve got a version of your application downloaded from the Android Market, it won´t install the debug version unless you sign it with the same certificate. Uninstall it, then

Comment: Yes, I tried uninstall and make a clean install. Also I publish apk as beta-test via google play and it installs on other devices normally and on my device it shows "Unknown error code 0" twice and on the third one it installs normally.

Comment: damn weird!!! :( sorry I cannot help you :((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've reinstalled Android on my phone and problem solved :) Not a good solution, but works.